# Can I use an ontology as database and store data within it?

Tags: database, ontology

I just started learning ontologies and Semantic Web. Now, I would like to build an application that uses an ontology. So I came across many examples of applications that use ontologies. All of these application have the same behaviour: they query the ontology for its data using a query language (e.g. SPARQL) and get the return results.

From this behaviour, UI see that ontologies are like databases: allowing to store and retrieve data. But I have seen also here on Stack Overflow that we should not use ontology as database. So my question is, why should we not? How are ontolgies not appropriate for serving as databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Semantic Web triple store can represent any data that you could store in any other database whether it be a relational database or a graph database. It is, in a sense the simplest form in which you can represent data: there is no simpler form because you can't represent data using only pairs, you need triples, and there is no more complex form that cannot be reduced to a triple store.

You absolutely can store data in a triple store, query it and get useful results and there are commercial and open source products on the market that do this.

On a plus side you can also store information about the way the information is stored, i.e. metadata in a triple store. Any predicate is itself an entity about which you can store information. This is not the case for all graph databases but it is for semantic web triple stores.

Also on the plus side you can reason about entities and their relationships using a 'reasoner'.

BUT, and it's a fairly large but, on the negative side it's terribly inefficient when you want to represent the type of information stored in most relational databases which is tables of data where each row has the same columns and where you don't need to reason about the stored data or the columns themselves.

So, depending on the application you will choose between a relational database, a document database, a graph database or a triple store.

Comment: Thank you @Ian Mercer, your explanation was very clear. I just like to know from you  some appropriate examples of using triple store.

Comment: @GB11 Here's one: http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/bbcinternet/2012/04/sports_dynamic_semantic.html